# Open a webpage in python in default browser, in a specific named window

Tags: python, browser, html

In Python, is there a way to open a specific url in the default browser, and specify the target name of the window to open it into?

I suppose you can do that using an automation framework such as selenium, but is there a solution which is not so "heavy"?

The html equivalent of this is a "a href" link with the target specified.

Comment: What is heavy? Posting an question on [so] is every aspect heavier than googling "python webbrowser open" and hitting the first thing that is presented ( the "webbrowser" module in the standard library).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a indicates that '[t]he following keywords have special meanings' for the `target` attribute: `_self, _blank, _parent,` and `_top`. This would appear to be at odds with what you are asking about; would you please clarify?

Comment: please post the command you would use with the webbrowser module (which i'm aware of obviously), that would open the url in a window named "xyz".  The test would be to send the command to open that url twice, and make it open in the same tab, so you would have one "instance" of that page and not two.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? I'm trying to avoid reopening the same url in multiple tabs. I haven't found a workaround either (e.g. a bash script) that doesn't involve adding bulky dependencies like selenium

Comment: FWIW after some more digging it looks like react-dev-utils (part of create-react-app) is able to do something similar to this on macOS using applescript, but falls back to opening in a new tab every time on other devices. It looks like it also only searches for the URL, not the `target`: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/71facade56a0d0f3bcae22c12ecc93a791ce33d4/packages/react-dev-utils/openBrowser.js#L67

Answer (score 0):

Use webbrowser module:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

Comment: that is not enough to satisfy the requirements, read the last part of the question please.

Comment: Create a page using Tkinter, place your links with webbrowser.open_new  as a callback.